# angular2, RxJs filter observable results?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm calling a service and returning a json object. I'd like to filter the results but can't seem to get it to work. The request works fine and I'm passing in a keyword using a filter function. I've tried to console log it but it's returning an empty array.

Thank in advance.

```
 let keywords = 'defunkt';

this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users')
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.result = data,
        console.log(this.result.filter((keyword, index) => keywords.lastIndexOf(keyword) === index));
    },
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('done')
  );
```

Comment: Can you describe in english — not in code — what you expect your filter to do? You want to find the users with a specific keyword in their profile?

Comment: Hi There, I want to be able to search the object. As an example, in the endpoint I'm hitting above. All github users have a login. I'd like to pass in a search string once I have the object and return another array based on that.  In the code above as a test I tried pass in a keyword to filter on, but I'm assuming that I might have to flatten the array or something.

Comment: Got it. I have submitted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a service that would let you search Github users by their login:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class GithubSearchService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  byLogin(query: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users')
      .map(resp => resp.json())
      .mergeMap(val => val)  // <!-- this is important
      .filter((user: any) => user.login.includes(query));
  }

}
```

And now the code consuming this service:

```ts
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private search: GithubSearchService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.search.byLogin('van')
      .subscribe(results => console.log(results));
  }

}
```

Several remarks:

- In this implementation, filtering is done **on the client**. That means you're not searching through ALL Github users but only through the users returned by the API call (30 users by default, it seems). The Github API probably accepts parameters that let you do the filtering on the server.
- Note the use of the `mergeMap()` operator. It lets me **flatten** the array of users returned by the API and have each user emitted as a single, individual value in the observable. I did that so I could manipulate (and filter) each user individually with other RxJS operators, instead of having to deal with an array of users.
- I used [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check if the user's login *contains* the given search query (case-sensitive search). Since this part is pure JS, you can easily adapt it to filter by other criteria.

Comment: Hi @AngularFrance. This is great and thanks for answering the question. But I want to filter with the results outside the service as I have the results stored in a redux store. I keeps returning undefined but it's not... console.log("///", this.myStore.select('mykey')
           .subscribe(state =>

             console.log(state)
           ));

Comment: Hi Jimi. It's hard to help you based on the small piece of code you provided. Could you provide a Plunkr?